# Get para that doesn't have an immediate child

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the below pieces of HTML.

**block 1:**

```
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>1:11</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    this is a content with <strong>strong content</strong> this is some extra data.
  </p>
</div>
```

**block 2:**

```
<div>
   <p>
    this is extra content
  </p>
</div>
```

**block 3:**

```
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>1:11</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    this is content with this is some extra data.
  </p>
</div>
```

I want an XSLT that will retrieve only the first `p` node that is not having any `strong` as an immediate child.

The output that I want is

> for block 1 - this is a content with **strong content** this is some extra data.
> for block 2, this is working fine - this is extra content
> for block 3, this is working fine -  this is content with this is some extra data.

I tried the following XSLT `descendant::p[not(./strong)][1]`. this is not working for block 1. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore the whitespace-only text() nodes from pretty-printing, you could look for the first `text()` that are not whitespace or `strong`, and then test whether it is a `strong` element:

```
descendant::p[not((text()[normalize-space()]|strong)[1][self::strong])]
```